# Cake Bake, how is date created being added to SQL?

Tags: sql, cakephp

I feel like people are misunderstanding my question

obviously i saw
$this->User->save($this->request->data
but there is nothing in the model that saves save current time, how does cakephp know to do that? is it reading the sql saying hmm this says created when this saves i will add a date is that what is going on?

All this code was generated by cake bake through the terminal and i'm just trying to learn and modify

How is cake saving the created date? Where is that line of code that does that?

my sql is setup like

id  int(10)
email   varchar(64) 
username    varchar(50) 
password    varchar(50)
role    varchar(20)
created datetime
modified datetime

Here is my model

```
<?php
// app/Model/User.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'User'; //this decide the table used

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A email is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'role' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Here is my controller for add

```
  public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }
```

my view

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('role', array(
            'options' => array('admin' => 'Admin', 'editor' => 'Editor', 'guest' => 'Guest')
        ));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking someone else to read the docs for you.

Comment: I read the docs it doesn't say it.

Comment: Look at the code then. Tip: Model layer.

Comment: There is nothing in the model layer that says anything about        created datetime
modified datetime

Comment: Look in the save method of the model class.

Comment: i saw that but there is nothing in the model class that says created and modified are time date

Comment: If it's true that there *nothing* in the model layer that saves the created and modified time (even though I'm looking at the line of code right now) as you say, then we must assume those fields get filled by magic. Have you thoroughly search the model layer? YourModel.php, and AppModel.php, and Model.php?

Comment: In my app model its empty but it uses App::uses('Model', 'Model'); where is this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use below line

```
$this->User->save($this->request->data)
```

save method checks, if created and modified is not set than it set current datetime into it before mysql query execute.

Comment: but how does the software know, that those are created and modified date time values? i didn't set them in the model? are they reading the column name for sql and making a decision?

Comment: They are auto-added by Cake and then auto-updated on create/save. e.g. if you add a nullable field called 'created' of type DATETIME then when you save a new row Cake will automatically save the current date & time in that field. Cake bake will automatically add the 'created' field to tables it makes. It will add 'modified' as well - this will be updated whenever an existing record is changed.

Comment: i see thank you, i didn't know that. I'm learning and i just want to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It's updating these fields due to the Timestamp behavior being added to the model on Cake bake (if you have the created and modified columns in your table).

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }
}
```

You can find more about it here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html